# Not all Azure subscriptions accessible in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 Subscriptions in Azure:

[image: BizSpark-Subscription]
[image: Pay-As-You-Go Subscription incl. VS Ultimate]

When I try to connect to all of them using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise I can't select the Pay-As-You-Go one:

[image: Visual Studio Subscription Selector]

Now I can't access all the stuff from the other Subscription. What's the point here?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, except none of my subscriptions are listed. If I connect with an account that truly doesn't have any subscriptions, there is a message stating as much with a link to add a new one, but I don't see that when using my account with subscriptions.

Everything works fine in VS 2013

Comment: Any solution found to this issue?

Comment: @Marcus I added the answer. Sorry for delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around this inside the Azure Portal. You can move subscriptions between different directories. Ovbiously the Visual Studio has problems when subscriptions exist in different directories with different credentials now (former it just logged in everywhere I guess).

I only know how to move those subscriptions in the old portal. If you are logged in there, you choose the last menu item on the left called "Settings". There you have a page "Subscriptions". You can choose a subscriptions and then hit "Edit Directory" on the bottom. There you can change the directory for this subscription.

If you move all your subscriptions to one directory and log into that directory in VS everything will show up.

Comment: that "Edit Directory" menu is not found.

Comment: @JerryGoyal You are right. Since the new portal has Azure AD management tools now I guess it is ported to this area. I'll investigate this and try to find the point.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was connecting to Azure through the Server Explorer tab.  Once I did that the drop down in the publish dialog started showing both my subscriptions!

So no need to do anything on the portal anymore.